# jQuery (fully) expand and (partially) collapse div on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement rating functionality on my website.
I have the following `HTML`:

```
<div class="rating-container">
    <div class="stars">
    </div>
</div>
```

The `stars` div gets populated with 10 `fa fa-star` font-awesome star icons during runtime via `jQuery`

My `CSS` looks like this:

```
div.rating-container div.stars {
  display: block;
}
div.rating-container div.stars i {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

..And the final result looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do now is to only show 1 star instead of 10 when the page initially loads. Hovering over the 1 star should expand the `stars` div so that all 10 stars show and the user can rate - once the mouse leaves the `stars` div, it goes back to only showing one star. I'm trying to achieve this using `jQuery`'s `$(this).animate({ width: someWidthHere });` on the `$(".stars").hover()`function  but I can't seem to get it right.

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Update: per request, here is the (silly) test code I've tried:

```
$(function () {
        $(".stars").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).animate({ width: '100%' });
            },
            function () {
                $(this).animate({ width: '10%' });
            }
        );
    });
```

Which gives me this on hover:

[image]

Comment: What's the code you've tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully I understand your question correctly. You can get trigger an event for on and off like this:

```
$( ".stars" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( ".stars" ).animate({ width: "100px" },1000);
  }, function() {
    $( ".stars" ).animate({ width: "20px" },1000);
  }
);
```

Just an FYI, I think it might be better to just use css transitions and just use the .toggleClass() to expand and contract the div. It works better with some mobile browsers that have less processing power but either way works.

This is how you would do that with css:

```
.stars {
  width:20px;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 1s;
}
.stars:hover{
  width:100px;
}
```

Comment: your first implementation is actually what I've already tried, using percentages instead of pixels. Instead of only showing one star though, all of the stars stack vertically. See updated question.

Comment: I just realized that what I said about the .toggleClass() is not needed for the css implementation. are the stars you are displaying their own html elements? You might want to try to ensure that they stay inline by: `.stars{overflow:hidden;}` and maybe setting a fixed height.

Comment: I've already tried adding `overflow:hidden;` to `.stars` but I still face the same issue. each star icon is a font-awesome icon: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/star/

Comment: I tried it out. if you set the `.stars{height:26px; overflow:hidden;}` that should work. If not, you can have a div around the i elements and inside the div.stars that is the fixed pixel width. Then there is only one element to hide so it will not be able to start stacking.

Comment: yup, it works, thanks! I also realized that it works if you disable `display: inline-block;` on `.fa` via firebug. I tried overriding the behavior using `div.rating-container div.stars i.fa` but can't get that to work either.

Comment: Glad that works. If the height overriding the `inline-block;` is not working then I would double check the selectors (which look fine) and maybe use `!important;` in your css. Though I would avoid overriding font awesome if possible. Also, if your css is loaded after font awesome it will help give it a higher priority.